# Difficulties solving proving equality

Tags: complex-analysis

Having difficulties proving this equality:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{cos(x)}{x^2+a^2}dx = \frac{\pi e^{-a}}{a}$

So far I have identified that $\frac{cos(x)}{x^2+a^2} = \frac{Re(e^{ix})}{x^2+a^2}$ but I still don't know if this is the right way.